# best way of storing a list of words in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So I have an app that needs to take a local data (persistence) , which is basically a list of words, it is categorized into three categories.. in other words, technically speaking I would have 3 .txt file list of words that I would like to make it available in my app.

What is the best way to do this? There are many options in doing this, such as using core data (which I think might be an overkill) or NSUserDefaults, or a.plist. I can create 3 separate .plist file. Talking about how it will be used, I will have a UISegmentedControl with 3 tabs (representing the 3 txt file of words I have). I would like then to choose a random word from the list associated with the segment. Needed some advice and input on this. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I forgot to mention how many words approximately in a file, there are approximately 100 to 200 max of words in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like plists would be the way to go. Some of this would depend on how long the lists are and if they are changing or not.  Plists are easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use sqlite in addition to the ways you have mentioned.

Better You can use plists.

Reading and writing to plists have been explained well [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1).